# Dynamically Passing AJAX Parameters

Tags: php, ajax

How to pass POST datas dynamically in $.ajax. I will call this function from several of my php page. So the POST datas here need to add dynamically. Is that possible ?

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
     url: 'page.php',
     data:({ **need to pass dynamically**}),
     beforeSend:function(){
         .....
     }),
     success: function(){
         .....
     })  
});
```

Comment: What is your question?  What are you trying to send as data?  Just put the name of your object variable in there...

Comment: No i have these code in a seperate function, and i call this from several of my php pages. So i dont want to repeat these code again, i would like to add POST datas dynamically based on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'page.php',
    data:({ 
        "username" : <?php echo $username;?>,
        "password" : <?php echo $password;?>
    }),
    beforeSend:function(){
       */.....*/
    }),
    success: function(){
        /*...........*/
    })  
});
```

Or just build your own query:

```
<?php
$data = array(  'foo'=>'bar',
                'baz'=>'boom',
                'cow'=>'milk',
                'php'=>'hypertext processor'
);

$query = http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');
?>

url: 'page.php?' <?php echo $query;?>
```

[PHP build query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: You can also echo a json array inside your script tags, and javascript will interpret it as an object. So you can call the obj->username from inside your function.